# Passport Js + Nodejs + Expressjs, authenticated route

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have an application nodejs with authentication using passportjs hosted on kinghost.com. I have the following question: My application has a strange behavior, after running a POST to persist some html data, the application is being redirected to the login screen. I noticed that the redirect performed at the end of the POST request, the passportjs says the route is not authenticated "req.isAuthenticated ()"
Running the application in localhost mode does not occur. Would anyone have any idea what the problem was?

I think the problem may be the session, but because in localhost mode the problem does not occur, this is a question I have

**My passport js settings**

```
var express           = require('express');
var session           = require('express-session');
var cookieParser      = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser        = require('body-parser');
var logger            = require('morgan');
var path              = require('path');
var app               = express();
var passport          = require('passport');
var flash             = require('connect-flash');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "50mb"}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit:50000}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(session({
    secret: 'reis&turlwaysrunning',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
 } ));
app.use(logErrors);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.login = req.user;
    next();
});
```

Comment: what is the logger output? Also it could be a CORS issue. How are you configuring that? We may need more information to help solve this.

Comment: Thanks for the response justin.m.chase. But there is no error in logging after this behavior. What I found was the passportjs identifying that the logged in user is not authenticated to access a particular route. It looks like session expires on the submit. On CORS there is also no logging on this problem, the application is not accessed by a front running on another server.

Comment: What about logging in the browser? If you open up the browser developer tools are there any errors in the console? Who is doing the actual redirection? There has to be some logging about the 3xx status code that causes the redirection.

Comment: Yes, on the console inspecting the browser my route with status http 302 is displayed.  
I run an AJAX POST for route creation, in AJAX success is accomplished a window.location.replace (endpoint); In window.location.replace is where the problem that the browser console presents is. status http 302 and the path of my route used in window.location.replace